# Set custom header to hash key in Varnish

Tags: varnish

I want to see which request gets which hash key (`req.hash` in older versions, or setting the hash key using `hash_data()`),
but I can't find any documentation about how to read it in Version 4.0.

How do I set my custom header to the request key?

Like:

```
set res.header.X-HASH = get_hash_key();
```

**Only Version 4.0!** Like `req.hash` is not available in version 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the data making up the hash key using the varnishlog command.

On your Varnish server, run the command

```
varnishlog
```

Then when you make a request, you should see something like this in varnishlog's output:

```
11 VCL_call     c hash
11 Hash         c /index.html
11 Hash         c www.example.com
11 VCL_return   c hash
```

In this example, the middle two lines show the data that is being used to make up the hash key.